# How to retrieve in MySQL select result the characters/words that meet the LIKE requirements, not a whole line

Tags: mysql

The table that can be used as a reference point:

```
    CREATE TABLE TEST (
Owner varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
Devices varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO TEST (Owner,Devices) VALUES
('Peter', 'laptop,phone,tablet'),
('Joe', 'phone,laptop,tablet'),
('Eugene', 'phone,tablet,laptop');


mysql> SELECT Owner, Devices FROM TEST WHERE Devices LIKE '%Laptop%';
+--------+---------------------+
| Owner  | Devices             |
+--------+---------------------+
| Peter  | laptop,phone,tablet |
| Joe    | phone,laptop,tablet |
| Eugene | phone,tablet,laptop |
+--------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

LIKE Operator looks for a certain pattern, but MySQL result shows not only a matched pattern, but a whole string with a matched pattern.
Please advise if there is a way to show the result in the following way:

```
+--------+---------------------+
| Owner  | Devices(LIKE result)|
+--------+---------------------+
| Peter  | laptop              |
| Joe    | laptop              |
| Eugene | laptop              |
+--------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the word you are looking for in the Select:

```
SELECT Owner, "Laptop" FROM TEST WHERE Devices LIKE '%Laptop%';
```

Comment: "Laptop" just returns here what you type. Unfortunately, it is not a solution :(

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you are using the word "laptop" manually, then you can type it manually twice. If you are using it in a variable, then you can insert the variable in the Select part of the query just as easily as in the Where clause.

Comment: I just want to see only the clause(mentioned by LIKE in select statement) mysql finds. not the whole string

Comment: "Laptop" can be represented by any word here. No matter which word will replace "Laptop"in your example, it will be shown. LIKE is not working with it.

Comment: My previous comment is still valid. How are you typing this in, manually, or through a programming language like PHP?

Comment: I'm typing it in terminal

Answer (score 0):

```
   declare device varchar(50) 
   set  device = 'laptop'
   select Owner , device as Devices from test where Devices 
   like '%' + device + '%';
```

Comment: Seems there is an error in syntax that cannot let me to test it :(